# extconf.rb failure installing linecached19

Tags: ruby

```
[user@host ~]$ sudo gem install linecache19-0.5.12.gem 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing linecache19-0.5.12.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-ruby-dir
        --without-ruby-dir
        --with-ruby-include
        --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
        --with-ruby-lib
        --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize': Connection timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `open'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `connect'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168:in `request'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:239:in `block in read'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:286:in `connect'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:234:in `read'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:128:in `download'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:55:in `block in create_makefile_with_core'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:320:in `open'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:51:in `create_makefile_with_core'
        from extconf.rb:19:in `<main>'
Requesting http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p290.tar.gz


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache19-0.5.12 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out
```

How do I trace this error? Nothing in gem_make.out is particularly useful as far as I can tell:

```
/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-ruby-dir
        --without-ruby-dir
        --with-ruby-include
        --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
        --with-ruby-lib
        --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize': Connection timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `open'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `connect'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168:in `request'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:239:in `block in read'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:286:in `connect'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:234:in `read'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:128:in `download'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:55:in `block in create_makefile_with_core'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:320:in `open'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:51:in `create_makefile_with_core'
        from extconf.rb:19:in `<main>'
Requesting http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p290.tar.gz
```

My deployment requires ruby 1.9.2p290, so upping versions isn't an option sadly. HOw do I get the additional libraries/headers the error seems to be asking for?

Comment: it looks like the ruby_core_source gem is trying to get the file http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p290.tar.gz do you have access to it? perhaps you are behind a proxy or something that's blocking it?

Answer (score 0):

Your deployment requires 1.9.2 and your backtrace says you are using 1.9.1. Maybe switching to the correct ruby version works.

Also, if your applications includes `ruby-debug19` (which requires `linecached19`), try to switch to simply `debugger`.